# SQL how to insert from another table based on same row values?

Tags: sql

I have two tables with similar column values for columns "name" and "regis". One table is already filled with values, the other has only values for "name". How do i get "regis" values from table1 into table2 based on same column values?

I tried something like this

```
INSERT INTO table2 (regis)
SELECT table1 (regis)
WHERE table2.name = table1.name
```

Comment: Please tag database.  Your question is bit ambiguous.  Do you want to update the regis column with matching values on name? or insert again if name match is found?

Comment: MySQL: `update table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.name = t1.name
set t2.regis = t1.regis;`

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are after is insert when name not found in table2 or update if its found in both tables.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (regis)
SELECT t1.REGIS FROM TABLE1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 as t2 on t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name is null
```

You can update table2 using the statement like below:

```
update t2
   set t2.regis = t1.regis
from table2 as t2
inner join table1 as t1 on t1.name = t2.name
```

If you are using SQL Server, then you can use [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement to either insert or update in one step.

Comment: i dont understand the syntax, what is t2 and t1?

Comment: t2 and t1 are the aliases.

Comment: unfortunately, the insert statement doesnt work. i get  error #1052 1052: Column 'regis' in field list is ambiguous. the update statement has wrong syntax error #1064

Comment: Updated my insert statement which now says take table1 regis.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
update table2 set regis = (select regis from table1 where table1.name=table2.name);
```

see the whole sample on:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jC8PGeZZEuty3XVq8gdzz/9

Comment: thanks i tried this but there is an error: error-1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row

Comment: are there duplicate rows with the same "name"?  If so, how to get the same value of "regis"?  try this: 
`update table2 set regis = (select regis from table1 where table1.name=table2.name limit 1);`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use table2 as join in your select statement.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (regis)
SELECT table1.regis FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

Comment: i tried this but it removed all table2.name values. any fix?

Comment: it should not be, paste your query